# Polymer.importPath in LitElement

Tags: polymer-3.x, lit-element

Polymer treats relative URLs as [relative to main document](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#urls-in-templates).
Polymer 3 provides a [[importPath]] value for relative URLs.
LitElement does not provide this helper. 
What is the best way to handle relative paths in LitElement using Polymer CLI build process ?

Comment: If you are using webpack you can use a loader that will do that for you

Comment: Thank you. I am using polymer cli build command.

Comment: I ended up with
```src="${new URL('relative/file.js', import.meta.url)}```
as the correct syntax for media src relative path.
There seems to be some compatibility issues with Edge though...

Answer (score 0):

Polymer needed `[[importPath]]` due to using HTML imports.

Lit uses ES6 modules, so you can get the current path with `import.meta.url`.

As there is a built in browser mechanism to access the URL Lit doesn't provide its own (which is core design principle of Lit), but there is a way to shim it - throw and catch an `Error` and the `stack` property will include the current file. I don't recommend it though as the browser versions that support modules but not `import.meta` are extremely obscure.